# Trying to store array values into cells in an excel sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've been having some problems with storing some calculated values into an excel sheet in specific cells. The complete code is lengthy but I've posted it below. While running with the debugger what I've found is that it is failing when it tries to store this first value in the first step of the following for loop:

```
    For i = 1 To 100
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cmatrix(i, 1)
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cmatrix(i, 2)
    Next i
```

I've also tried it with `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value` but I still just get a #VALUE! error during the first line of the for loop. I've also tried with and without the `.Value`
The `Cmatrix` is declared as a variant but I've also declared it as a double before just to see. It is an array from 1-100 and 1-2. I've even tried just setting it equal to 1 but the same problem arrises.
The overall code is rather lengthy but is here with the problem area being closer to the bottom:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Test(check As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Response As Integer
    If check = 1 Then
        Response = MsgBox("Boundary Condition 1 selected, is this correct (select No for boundary condition 2)?", vbYesNo, "Boundary Conditions")
        If Response = 6 Then
            Test = 1
        Else
            Test = 2
        End If
    ElseIf check = 2 Then
        Response = MsgBox("Boundary Condition 2 selected, is this correct (select No for boundary condition 1)?", vbYesNo, "Boundary Conditions")
        If Response = 6 Then
            Test = 2
        Else
            Test = 1
        End If
    Else
        Response = MsgBox("Incorrect Boundary Condition, select Yes for condition 1 and No for condition 2", vbYesNo, "Boundary Conditions")
        If Response = 6 Then
            Test = 1
        Else
            Test = 2
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Sub Check2(x)
    MsgBox ("Value given is outside data range, answer may not be correct, extrapolating from calculated polynomial")
End Sub


Public Function cubic(ByVal r As Range, x As Double, Optional check As Integer = 1) As Double
    Dim data() As Double
    Dim check1 As Integer
    Dim Smatrix() As Double
    Dim Tmatrix() As Double
    Dim Xmatrix() As Double
    Dim Amatrix() As Double
    Dim Hmatrix() As Double
    Dim Cmatrix(1 To 100, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim step As Double
    Dim chart As Range, c As Range
    
    m = r.Rows.Count
    ReDim data(1 To m, 2)
    ReDim Smatrix(1 To m, 1 To m)
    ReDim Tmatrix(1 To m, 4)
    ReDim Xmatrix(1 To m)
    ReDim Amatrix(1 To m - 1, 1 To 4)
    ReDim Hmatrix(1 To m)

    check1 = Test(check)
    
    For i = 1 To m
        data(i, 1) = r(i, 1).Value
        data(i, 2) = r(i, 2).Value
    Next i
    
    Smatrix(1, 1) = 1
    Smatrix(m, m) = 1
    
    For i = 1 To m - 1
        Hmatrix(i) = data(i + 1, 1) - data(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    If check1 = 2 Then
        Smatrix(1, 2) = -1
        Smatrix(m, m - 1) = -1
    End If
    
    For i = 2 To m - 1
        Smatrix(i, i - 1) = Hmatrix(i - 1)
        Smatrix(i, i + 1) = Hmatrix(i)
        Smatrix(i, i) = 2 * (Hmatrix(i - 1) + Hmatrix(i))
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To m - 1
        Tmatrix(i, 4) = 6 * ((data(i + 1, 2) - data(i, 2)) / Hmatrix(i) - (data(i, 2) - data(i - 1, 2)) / Hmatrix(i - 1))
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To m
        If i <> 1 Then
            Tmatrix(i, 1) = Smatrix(i, i - 1)
        End If
        
        Tmatrix(i, 2) = Smatrix(i, i)
        
        If i <> m Then
            Tmatrix(i, 3) = Smatrix(i, i + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To m
        Tmatrix(i, 1) = Tmatrix(i, 1) / Tmatrix(i - 1, 2)
        Tmatrix(i, 2) = Tmatrix(i, 2) - Tmatrix(i, 1) * Tmatrix(i - 1, 3)
        Tmatrix(i, 4) = Tmatrix(i, 4) - Tmatrix(i, 1) * Tmatrix(i - 1, 4)
    Next i
    
    Xmatrix(m) = Tmatrix(m, 4) / Tmatrix(m, 2)
    For i = m - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Xmatrix(i) = (Tmatrix(i, 4) - Tmatrix(i, 3) * Xmatrix(i + 1)) / Tmatrix(i, 2)
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To m - 1
        Amatrix(i, 1) = (Xmatrix(i + 1) - Xmatrix(i)) / 6 * Hmatrix(i)
        Amatrix(i, 2) = Xmatrix(i) / 2
        Amatrix(i, 3) = (data(i + 1, 2) - data(i, 2)) / Hmatrix(i) - Hmatrix(i) * Xmatrix(i) / 2 - Hmatrix(i) * (Xmatrix(i + 1) - Xmatrix(i)) / 6
        Amatrix(i, 4) = data(i, 2)
    Next i
    step = (data(m, 1) - data(1, 1)) / 100
    For i = 0 To (m - 1)
        Cmatrix(i + 1, 1) = data(1, 1) + i * step
    Next i
    For j = 1 To m
        If Cmatrix(j, 1) = data(m, 1) Then
            Cmatrix(j, 2) = data(m, 2)
        Else
            For i = 1 To m - 1
                If data(i, 1) < Cmatrix(j, 1) And Cmatrix(j, 1) < data(i + 1, 1) Then
                    Cmatrix(j, 2) = Amatrix(i, 1) * (Cmatrix(j, 1) - data(i, 1)) ^ 3 + Amatrix(i, 2) * (Cmatrix(j, 1) - data(i, 1)) ^ 2 + Amatrix(i, 3) * (Cmatrix(j, 1) - data(i, 1)) + Amatrix(i, 4)
                ElseIf Cmatrix(j, 1) = data(i, 1) Then
                    Cmatrix(j, 2) = data(i, 2)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next j
    If x < data(1, 1) Or x > data(m, 1) Then
        Call Check2(x)
        If x < data(1, 1) Then
            cubic = Amatrix(1, 1) * (x - data(1, 1)) ^ 3 + Amatrix(1, 2) * (x - data(1, 1)) ^ 2 + Amatrix(1, 3) * (x - data(1, 1)) + Amatrix(1, 4)
        ElseIf x > data(m, 1) Then
            cubic = Amatrix(m - 1, 1) * (x - data(m - 1, 1)) ^ 3 + Amatrix(m - 1, 2) * (x - data(m - 1, 1)) ^ 2 + Amatrix(m - 1, 3) * (x - data(m - 1, 1)) + Amatrix(m - 1, 4)
        End If
    ElseIf x = data(m, 1) Then
        cubic = data(m, 2)
    Else
        For i = 1 To m - 1
            If data(i, 1) < x And x < data(i + 1, 1) Then
                cubic = Amatrix(i, 1) * (x - data(i, 1)) ^ 3 + Amatrix(i, 2) * (x - data(i, 1)) ^ 2 + Amatrix(i, 3) * (x - data(i, 1)) + Amatrix(i, 4)
            ElseIf x = data(i, 1) Then
                cubic = data(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    For i = 1 To 100
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cmatrix(i, 1)
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cmatrix(i, 2)
    Next i
    Set chart = Range("A1:B100")
    Dim cht As Object
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=xlXYScatterSmooth)
    cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=chart
End Function
```

Comment: How many rows do you have? It's generally recommended to use `Long` instead of `Int` for row/column counts as it can hold a higher number.

Comment: @BruceWayne only 100 rows. I thought that integer counters could go up to 32000. I replaced it with a `Long` and ran into the same problem

Comment: You state that you are getting a #VALUE! error. Is that accurately stated? #VALUE! is a spreadsheet calculation error; it suggests a problem with the data you are trying to write to the cell, rather than a problem with your logic. What are the values of `Cmatrix(i, 1)` and `Cmatrix(i, 2)` when you get this error?

Comment: How are you calling the function?  From VBA or from a worksheet cell?

Comment: @BDra I took a screenshot of some sample values for example. They seem to be stored correctly. I've also tried to just write `1` to the cells and came into the same problem so I am at a loss. https://imgur.com/a/3STvBwF

Comment: @TimWilliams I've been calling the original function from a worksheet cell

Comment: I just recently tried adding the for loop to the beginning of the code and just putting     `Dim k As Long
    For k = 1 To 100
        Cells(k, 1).Value = 1
        Cells(k, 2).Value = 1
    Next k` and I'm running into the same problem. It stores nothing in the cells and crashes immediately

Comment: You cannot update cells from a function called as a UDF from a worksheet cell: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.   The function can only return a value (or array of values)

Comment: @TimWilliams yes I ended up running it through a sub and a macro. Thanks!